# Get the array of strings by matching the pattern in the given string

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern `@@{}` and given a string I need to find out all the strings coming in between the curly braces.

Example : 
If my string is `Hi This is @@{first} and second is @@{second} along with third @@{third} string`

The output I expect is a string array consisting of elements:

```
first   
second  
third
```

My Java code for this goes as :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\@\\@\\{(.+?)\\}");    
Matcher match = p.matcher("Hi This is @@{first} and second is @@{second} along" +
                          "with third @@{third} string");
while(match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group());   
}
```

But the output which I am getting is

```
@@{first}   
@@{second}  
@@{third}
```

Please guide me how to get the desired output and what mistake I am doing

Comment: By the way, looking at your earlier questions... if an answer solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as "accepted" by ticking the green checkmark on the left.

Comment: +1 for very clearly written question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `match.group()` into `match.group(1)`. Also, `@` needs no escaping.